# Getting back a 1x1 pixel, blank IMG in facebook API oauth for the user profile. rails / haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, haml

When I do

```
%img{:src => "#{current_user.image}"}
```

It will not display the image on the page.

If I use the chrome element inspector, I can see the correct link:

```
<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/38400928/picture">
```

I can right click through that and choose to view the link in a new window, which it does.

For some reason though, I cannot get this to display on my site.

Does anyone know what's going on ? If I can link to it, it should be able to show through the link, correct...? :/

I will point out that I am new to rails and haml. Trying to learn as I go.

---

also, iv'e seen others state that it's an issue with not specifying httpS:// instead of http.

I just tried to manually enter https to test it, but no luck... :(

```
 %img{:src => "https://graph.facebook.com/38400928/picture"}
```

tried this while logged in.. didn't render the image..

Answer (score 1):

### Update: I created [a blog post](https://pgord.wordpress.com/2015/03/03/avatars-with-devise-omniauth-facebook-carrierwave-and-aws-s3/) for this.

It looks like you're just storing the user's avatar as a URL. I would suggest storing the user's avatar as a file when they sign up using the OAuth.

One way I have done this is with:

- [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)
- [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)
- [Omniauth-Facebook](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook)
- Fog (see CarrierWave)
- [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)

With this approach, instead of just storing the `current_user.image` as a URL to Facebook you actually upload it to your storage on AWS and then display that.

If you think it'd be helpful I can probably write a reasonably quick tutorial on how to do this.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes. It would be extremely helpful - if you don't mind. I've used S3 before, but in nodeJS.

Comment: OK - are you currently using any of those gems?

Comment: It seems i only have the omniAuth for FB.

Comment: I will install the others, though.

Comment: Alright - I'm writing a reasonably quick tutorial. I'll link it here when its done.

Comment: Added the blog post link to the answer